# capture ajax events between postback asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, progress-bar

I am building an Asp.net MVC3 web application and i am facing a problem and need help in how to resolve that problem.

the task is create an import page to import user data into web site.

the problem in

1. the long time that import may take due to large data the user may have. So i decided to work with Ajax to let user navigate and complete his work while import is in progress in background but how i can create a progress bar for user and make it visible during postbacks in the bottom of the page.
2. i faced another problem postback would cause my ajax call to be terminated.

any suggestion on how to solve this problems

Comment: What's the source data to import in Website ?

Comment: What do you mean by source data to import? if i understand your point its user data like products information

Comment: Are u using Excel file to import data ?

Comment: yes excel file as a template after user download the file he should upload it again with his data as csv file then import process begin

Comment: can you Bulk import the data using `SqlBulkCopy`? This will insert all records in one shot. Create a Stored proc and insert the data in respective tables.

Comment: @PankajGarg I am using Linq to SQL i don't know if i can create SQLBulkCopy or not but i will try that thanks in advance

Comment: My response was in regard to the performance only. It should remove the need of progress bar. Are u importing one by one record at the moment?  Also `SQLBulkCopy` class belongs to very old .net Framework. So please hold on and wait for other suggestions `(if possible)`. You have good rep. Let's start a bounty for this good question ?

Comment: @PankajGarg for now i am importing records to a model then loop into that model and insert all that in my context first then after insertion complete i commit that to database with that way i have the ability to make some checks in data to avoid mistaking data

Comment: **Linq to SQL** also supports access stored proc. ** for now i am importing records to a model then loop into that model** - Send all record in db using `SqlBulkCopy`. **with that way i have the ability to make some checks in data to avoid mistaking data** This is a slow process. Using Stored proc u can select all problems records in one select statement. and return the problem records as message to user.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue? I am facing the same issue and I want to resolve it in the best way possible.